# In Debian Linux can I build a single driver to become permanently part of my kernel image and part of my vmlinux file (for debugging)

Tags: linux-device-driver

I've got a custom kernel that I've built locally with gdb and kgdb enabled and installed.  I have the vmlinux file for it that I use for source level kgdb.  Each time I make a change I've been rebuilding the entire kernel.  But I want to become more efficient than rebuilding whole kernels for every code change.

So I made a mod to my ata driver.  Then I did a

make M=drivers/ata

It succeeded.  Now how do I replace my previous ata driver with this ata driver and get this updated info into my vmlinux file for source debugging this new driver.

I'm not considering doing an insmod.  I want to permanently modify my kernel image to replace the previous ata driver with this ata driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is not possible to replace a driver in the Linux binary with a new version. You must use `insmod`, or recompile the entire kernel. I do not see any problem to recompile the whole kernel. If you already compiled it before, it takes few seconds

Comment: But installing an entire new kernel is a pain isn't it?

Comment: checkout the kernel version that you are using, copy the previous configuratio file, run make, replace the image. More or less is what you have to do